# ParametricNDSolve with a delay differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, list-manipulation, ecology

I have a set of delay differential equations that I solve numerically from `0 < t < T`.  `y[T]`  is then used as the initial condition for `z` to start the next round. I would like to keep track of the evolution of `y[T]` for different values of `ta`. I planned to do this by generating the list  `ytotal` for different values of `ta` using `Table`.

```
x0 = 10^8; a = 10^-8;  dv = 2; d = 0.5; T = 4; b = 200;
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{
    x'[t] == -d x[t] - a *x[t]*z[t],
    y'[t] == a b Exp[-d ta]*x[t - ta]*z[t - ta] - dv y[t],
    z'[t] == -dv z[t],
    x[t /; t <= 0] == x0, y[t /; t <= 0] == 0, 
    z[t /; t <= 0] == z0}, 
   {x, y, z}, {t, 0, T}, {z0, ta}, MaxStepSize -> 10^1000, 
   Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}, MaxSteps -> 10^6, 
   WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];
{z0 = 1; ytotal[ta] = {z0};
   For[i = 0, i < 100, i++,
  {z0 = Evaluate[y[z0, ta][T] /. sol];
   ytotal[ta] = Append[ytotal[ta], z0];
   zeq[ta] = Last[ytotal[ta]]}]}
```

My current approach is not working. I thought it might be because of an issue arising from using `ParametricNDSolve` to vary the delay `ta`. Also, I am using a `For` loop which I know is advised against in Mathematica but I couldn't figure out how to iterate `sol` without one.

Comment: To be sure, you want to solve until `t == T` for a given `ta`, then change `ta` and do it again?

Comment: I want to keep the same ```ta``` for all 100 iterates. The goal is to generate lists of  ```y[T]``` for different values of ```ta``` over 100 iterates.

Comment: It seems that restarting the numerical integration with only `t == 0` initial conditions loses the history between iterates then.  Do you even need to stop & restart `NDSolve`?

Comment: Yes, I think I do need to restart numerical integration because I need to reset ```y[0] == 0``` and ```z[0] == z0```. (```z0 = y[T]```)

Comment: Hmm, it's more complex than I thought!  Could you add some explanation of what you're modeling?  When `z0` becomes `y[T]`, should it also inherit `y[t]`'s history?

Comment: This is a MWE of a host parasite system. ```x[t]``` is the host, ```z[t]``` is the first generation of parasites and ```y[t]``` is the second generation of parasites. ```ta``` is longer than the time the host spends in a susceptible developmental stage so when ```z[t]``` are produced they need to wait until new susceptible hosts are available in the next time period. When ```z0``` becomes ```y[T]```, I don't need the entire history of ```y[t]```, just the size at ```y[T]```.

Comment: `ta` and `v10` are undefined in the code.  Also, why not solve for `z` and `x` symbolically?

Comment: I fixed the typo for ```v10```. Ideally I would define a function so I could get ```zeq[ta]``` for different values of ```ta```. This is a simplification of a more complex model so I need a numerical approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to get what you want is with `Table`:

```
z0 = 1; ta = 0.01;
ytotal[ta] = Table[z0 = y[z0, ta][T] /. sol, {i, 100}];
```

For those parameter values, it looks like the population quickly goes extinct:

```
ListPlot[ytotal[ta], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you change parameters they can persist.

I'm not an expert in delay differential equation models, but I'm a bit concerned about how the initial history of `z[t]` might introduce artifacts in your results.  A priori, I imagined that increasing the developmental delay `ta` would hurt the parasite but instead it seemed to help.  But then I figured that for `t < ta`, `y[t]` would be increasing due to the `a b Exp[-d ta]*x[t - ta]*z[t - ta]` term, but were there really any first generation parasites `z[t]` running around when `t < 0`?  Seems delicate.  I tried a different initial history `z[t /; t <= 0] == If[t < 0, 0, z0]` but that often led to numerical problems (`ParametricNDSolve::ndsz -- step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected`).  What do you think?

Comment: I think I should be able to get this work. Thanks for your help! And yes, longer delays help the parasite in this case.

Comment: Glad it helps. I suppose d < dv means the parasite would rather hang out in the host?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it